# MVC LabelFor to replace underscores with CamelCase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

my DB model has the column name with  "_" in the field name.
is there a way to dislay these values in Camel Case when displaying in the form? like
"BusinessName"

i am using asp.net MVC3 with Razor

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.business_name)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you not just use the [DisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx)?

Comment: +1, that's the correct way. Add to your answer that view models should be used instead of some EF autogenerated domain entities into the views and your answer will be perfect. Also instead of saying *Could you not just use ...* you should say *You should use ...*.

Comment: Yes, I would have said, "You should", but I guess I answered in the form of a question because I wanted to share that tidbit of info, but also ask if it was appropriate for his application. I also totally agree about using View Models, which is what I do. I do not like decorating my domain entities with attributes, but rather create View Models and decorate those. Thanks for the +1.

Comment: i am using Edmx file with db first. how can i use disaplyattribute

Answer (score 5):

You need a new metadataprovider which can inherit from the default one like this:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        if (metadata.DisplayName == null)
            metadata.DisplayName = GetDisplayNameFromDBName(propertyName);

        return metadata;
    }

    private string GetDisplayNameFromDBName(string propertyName)
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Register it in global.asax like this:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MyMetadataProvider();
```

You just need to provide the implementation of GetDisplayNameFromDBName to provide the correct display name given the property name

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use @Html.Label("Business name")?